# Need help with Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I have a Toshiba Satellite-L655 laptop with Windows 7, and I want to install 12.04 LTS.

The problem is that I have a problem with Windows. The problem is that, when I turn on my laptop, it gives this options: "start up repair (recommended) and "Start Up Normally".

If I choose Start Up Normally it goes to Start Up Repair anyway.

When Start Up Repair runs, it says "startup repair is checking your system for problems".

This goes for like 7 minutes, then it says that it couldn't fix the problem, so I can't use Windows.

I was wondering if I was able to install Ubuntu in somehow.

If possible, please tell me and help me.

Comment: Sergio, could you clarify this: have you managed to install Ubuntu yet, or is it just Windows for now?
If the first: do you think the Ubuntu installation broke Windows?

Comment: No.

I've used Ubuntu before, alongside with windows, but with another Laptopt.

My Toshiba doesn't work (But it has nothing to do with Ubuntu).

A few weeks ago it showed me the "startup repair is checking your system for problems" and then  it says that it couldn't fix the problem, and doesn't start windows.

So, I'm asking if I can install Ubuntu with these conditions.

Comment: It seems like that your windows installation is corrupt.  Do you want to keep windows?

Comment: Not at all sir.

Comment: So what's the problem. Don't you have an install medium?

Comment: No, I just have a USB with Ubuntu in it.

Comment: Then you're good to go. I'll elaborate a bit in the answer below :)

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood, or if you need more information

Comment: I don't know what's your problem with installing Ubuntu over Windows, but could it be that you don't know how to boot from the USB Stick?

Answer (score 1):

Just connect your USB stick in the pc, power on and press F12 for the advanced boot menu and choose USB.

If you have any files on the disk you need to keep, choose "Try Ubuntu" (be patient, it might be slow) and make a copy of your files somewhere else.

Then reboot and choose "install Ubuntu", entire disk. It will erase the windows partition and reformat it.

Follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your comments that you don't need to keep Windows. If I understand you correctly, you just want a fresh Ubuntu installation.

You're good to go. Ubuntu won't care if Windows is not working if you use the USB as installation medium.

There is plenty of documentation on this on the net. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the Windows system, you may install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a VM (virtual machine).

If you want to remove the Windows system and reinstall Ubuntu 12.4, you just need boot your laptop on ubuntu DVD, click Install Ubuntu, provide the information requested by the installer, and let the installer install the OS.

Comment: I don't understand how installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine will help.